# jq - parse structure and save values in bash variable

Tags: json, linux, bash, loops, jq

I have a json input as follow

```
{
  "unique": 1924,
  "coordinates": [
    {
      "time": "2015-01-25T00:00:01.683",
      "xyz": [
        {
          "z": 4,
          "y": 2,
          "x": 1,
          "id": 99,
          "inner_arr" : [
          {
              "a": 1,
              "b": 2
          },
          {
              "a": 3,
              "b": 4
          }
          ]
        },
        {
          "z": 9,
          "y": 9,
          "x": 8,
          "id": 100,
          "inner_arr" : [
          {
              "a": 1,
              "b": 2
          },
          {
              "a": 3,
              "b": 4
          }
          ]
        },
        {
          "z": 9,
          "y": 6,
          "x": 10,
          "id": 101,
          "inner_arr" : [
          {
              "a": 1,
              "b": 2
          },
          {
              "a": 3,
              "b": 4
          }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "time": "2015-01-25T00:00:02.790",
      "xyz": [
        {
          "z": 0,
          "y": 3,
          "x": 7,
          "id": 99,
         "inner_arr" : [
          {
              "a": 1,
              "b": 2
          },
          {
              "a": 3,
              "b": 4
          }
          ]
        },
        {
          "z": 4,
          "y": 6,
          "x": 2,
          "id": 100,
          "inner_arr" : [
          {
              "a": 1,
              "b": 2
          },
          {
              "a": 3,
              "b": 4
          }
          ]
        },
        {
          "z": 2,
          "y": 9,
          "x": 51,
          "id": 101,
          "inner_arr" : [
          {
              "a": 1,
              "b": 2
          },
          {
              "a": 3,
              "b": 4
          }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to parse this input with jq and store values in bash arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

z=()
x=()
y=()
id=()
a=()
b=()

jq --raw-output '.coordinates[] | .xyz[] | (.z) as $z, (.y) as $y,7 (.x) as $x, (.id) as $id, .inner_arr[].a $a, .inner_arr[].b as $b | $z, $y, $x, $id, $a, $b' <<< "$input"


echo -e "${z}"
```

Expected output for above echo command:

```
4
9
9
0
4
2

echo -e "${a}"
```

Expected output for above echo command:

```
1
3
1
3
1
3
1
3
1
3
1
3
```

How can I do it with jq with a single jq call looping through all arrays in a cascading fashion?
I want to save CPU by calling jq just once and extract all single or array values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set environment variable directly from jq (cf. [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#$ENV,env)). What you can do is to generate a series of bash declarations for the `declare` builtin. I suggest to store the declarations in an intermediate bash array (with `mapfile`) processed directly by `declare` so that you can stay away from hazardous commands like `eval`.

```
mapfile -t < <(
    jq --raw-output '
        def m(exp): first(.[0] | path(exp)[-1]) + "=(" + (map(exp) | @sh) + ")";
        [ .coordinates[].xyz[] ]
        | m(.x), m(.y), m(.z), m(.id), m(.inner_arr[].a), m(.inner_arr[].b)
    ' input
)

declare -a "${MAPFILE[@]}"
```

The jq script packs all `xyz` objects in a single array and filters it with the `m` function for each field represented as a path expression. The function returns a string formatted as `field=(val1 val2... valN)`, where the field name is the last component of the path expression, i.e. `x` for `.x` and `a` for `.inner_arr[].a` (extracted on the first item of the array).

Then you can check the shell variables with `declare -p var` or `${var[@]}`. `${var}` refers to the first element only.

```
declare -p MAPFILE
declare -p z
echo a: "${a[@]}" / size = ${#a[@]}
```

---

```
declare -a MAPFILE=([0]="x=(1 8 10 7 2 51)" [1]="y=(2 9 6 3 6 9)" [2]="z=(4 9 9 0 4 2)" [3]="id=(99 100 101 99 100 101)" [4]="a=(1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3)" [5]="b=(2 4 2 4 2 4 2 4 2 4 2 4)")
declare -a z=([0]="4" [1]="9" [2]="9" [3]="0" [4]="4" [5]="2")
a: 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 / size = 12
```